# Tensorflow multi-dimension argmax

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have a tensor of size BxWxHxD. I want to process the tensor such that I have a new BxWxHxD tensor where only the maximum element in each WxH slice is kept, and all other values are zero.

In other words, I think the best way to achieve this is to somehow take a 2D argmax across the WxH slices, resulting in BxD index tensors for the rows and colums that can then be converted to a one-hot BxWxHxD tensor to be used as a mask. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following function as a starting point. It calculates the indexes of the maximum element for each batch and for each channel. The resulting array is in the format (batch size, 2, number of channels).

```
def argmax_2d(tensor):

  # input format: BxHxWxD
  assert rank(tensor) == 4

  # flatten the Tensor along the height and width axes
  flat_tensor = tf.reshape(tensor, (tf.shape(tensor)[0], -1, tf.shape(tensor)[3]))

  # argmax of the flat tensor
  argmax = tf.cast(tf.argmax(flat_tensor, axis=1), tf.int32)

  # convert indexes into 2D coordinates
  argmax_x = argmax // tf.shape(tensor)[2]
  argmax_y = argmax % tf.shape(tensor)[2]

  # stack and return 2D coordinates
  return tf.stack((argmax_x, argmax_y), axis=1)

def rank(tensor):

  # return the rank of a Tensor
  return len(tensor.get_shape())
```